# svn co equivalent of git clone --depth

Tags: git, svn

Is there any equivalent of `git clone --depth 1` in SVN? I need it to clone a large project:

```
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk
```

Comment: in SVN history stays on the server, every checkout is of depth 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well SVN is a centralized version control, so you don't ever really "clone" an entire repo.  However, I would say "checkout" is what you are looking for:

[Documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html)

[TortoiseSVN Documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use git for access to LLVM, you can use the official [git mirror](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#git-mirror).